# Torsion on a flat connection (Geometric Intuition).

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections, tangent-bundle, pullback

Start with the 2-sphere $\mathcal{S}^2$ with the standard $(\theta, \phi)$ chart ($\theta = 0$ is the North pole etc) and metric:

$$ds^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2$$

Remove the two poles from $\mathcal{S}^2$ and the arc $\phi=\pi$ to get $\mathcal{S}^2_0$. Let $A:=(0, \pi) \times (-\pi, \pi) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Next define the standard diffeomorphism $f: A \rightarrow \mathcal{S}^2_0$ between the two manifolds and let $f^*(T\mathcal{S}^2_0)$ be the corresponding [bundle-pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)#Pullback_of_bundles_and_sections) of the Tangent Bundle of $\mathcal{S}^2_0$. Construct the connection $\nabla_T$ on $\mathcal{S}^2_0$ (T for Torsion) where $\Gamma_{\theta \phi}^{\phi} = \cot\theta$ and all the other connection coefficients are zero.

It can be shown that $\nabla_T$ is metric compatible and flat (ie. of zero curvature) but it has Torsion. One can also define the [connection-pullback](https://diffgeom.subwiki.org/wiki/Pullback_of_connection_on_a_vector_bundle) of $\nabla_T$ which is essentially the unique connection on $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, call it $\nabla$, induced by the Tangent Bundle of $\mathcal{S}^2_0$ via its bundle-pullback. Can we picture this connection $\nabla$ on $A$? More generally:

> Can we visualize the non-zero Torsion of the pair ($\mathcal{S}^2_0$, $\nabla_T$) via the "flat" pair $(A, \nabla)$?

I am trying to gain **geometric** intuition so I can ultimately answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519950/what-do-the-fibers-tell-us-about-torsion-geometric-intuition/4618676#4618676) question on the relation between fibers and Torsion. Concrete calculations are of course welcome and they can add to the insight but they are *secondary* to me. Huge thanks to @Moishe Kohan and @Ted Shifrin for helping me with the phrasing of this question.

Comment: Still not right. When you remove two poles, the space is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$. In particular, the fact that this space is jot simply connected will lead to global issues even though things may be locally flat.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are correct thanks, I fixed it. My focus is more on the picture of the torsion for a (locally) flat connection.